# Get full computer name from a network drive letter in python

Tags: python, windows, network-drive, computer-name

I am using python to populate a table with the file pathways of a number of stored files. However the pathway needs to have the full network drive computer name not just the drive letter, ie

//ComputerName/folder/subfolder/file

not

P:/folder/subfolder/file

I have investigated using the win32api, win32file, and os.path modules but nothing is looking like its able to do it. I need something like `win32api.GetComputerName()` but with the ability to drop in a known drive letter as an argument and it return the computer name that is mapped to the letter.

So is there anyway in python to look up a drive letter and get back the computer name?

Answer (score 7):

Network drives are mapped using the [Windows Networking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385154) API that's exported by mpr.dll (multiple provider router). You can create a network drive via [`WNetAddConnection2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413). To get the remote path that's associated with a local device, call [`WNetGetConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385453). You can do this using ctypes as follows:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

mpr = ctypes.WinDLL('mpr')

ERROR_SUCCESS   = 0x0000
ERROR_MORE_DATA = 0x00EA

wintypes.LPDWORD = ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.DWORD)
mpr.WNetGetConnectionW.restype = wintypes.DWORD
mpr.WNetGetConnectionW.argtypes = (wintypes.LPCWSTR,
                                   wintypes.LPWSTR,
                                   wintypes.LPDWORD)

def get_connection(local_name):
    length = (wintypes.DWORD * 1)()
    result = mpr.WNetGetConnectionW(local_name, None, length)
    if result != ERROR_MORE_DATA:
        raise ctypes.WinError(result)
    remote_name = (wintypes.WCHAR * length[0])()
    result = mpr.WNetGetConnectionW(local_name, remote_name, length)
    if result != ERROR_SUCCESS:
        raise ctypes.WinError(result)
    return remote_name.value
```

For example:

```
>>> subprocess.call(r'net use Y: \\live.sysinternals.com\tools')
The command completed successfully.
0
>>> print(get_connection('Y:'))
\\live.sysinternals.com\tools
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you just need to look at more of pywin32...  As you can see [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32wnet.html), there is already an API that converts local drive names to full UNC paths.

For completeness, here is some code that works for me.

```
import win32wnet
import sys

print(win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName(sys.argv[1], 1))
```

And this gives me something like this when I run it:

```
C:\test>python get_unc.py i:\some\path
\\machine\test_share\some\path
```

Answer (score 0):

you could run `net use` and parse the output.

i am posting this from my mobile but i am going to improve this answer when i am in front of a real computer.

here are some links, that can help in the meantime:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg651155.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57300253/9560908):

Here's how to do it in python ≥ 3.4, with no dependencies!*

```py
from pathlib import Path

def unc_drive(file_path):
    return str(Path(file_path).resolve())
```

*Note: I just found a situation in which this method fails. One of my company's network shares has permissions setup such that this method raises a `PermissionError`. In this case, `win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName` is a suitable fallback.

Answer (score -1):

If you just need the hostname, you can use the `socket` module:

```
socket.gethostname()
```

or you may want to use the `os` module:

```
os.uname()[1]
```

`os.uname()` returns a 5 tuple that contains (sysname, nodename, release, version, machine)

Comment: `socket.gethostname()` appears to do exactly the same thing as `win32api.GetComputerName()` in that it returns the name of the local computer I need to be able to return the name of a mapped network drive `.uname` does not appear to exist as an object in the `os` module.

Comment: i think `uname` is only available on linux/unix systems. but it would also return the local computer name.