# Python 2: Get network share path from drive letter

Tags: python, python-2.7, unc, network-share

If I use the following to get the list of all connected drives:

```
available_drives = ['%s:' % d for d in string.ascii_uppercase if os.path.exists('%s:' % d)]
```

How do I get the UNC path of the connected drives?

`os.path` just returns `z:\` instead of `\share\that\was\mapped\to\z`

Comment: Note: I didn't try executing this. https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html  Based on this,  "Note On Windows, many of these functions do not properly support UNC pathnames. splitunc() and ismount() do handle them correctly".           os.path.splitunc(path)  Split the pathname path into a pair (unc, rest) so that unc is the UNC mount point (such as r'\\host\mount'), if present, and rest the rest of the path (such as r'\path\file.ext').                                              
  For paths containing drive letters, unc will always be the empty string.

Comment: Try the following library in the blog post. http://developer.covenanteyes.com/unc-paths-with-python/   The link to the library http://covenanteyes.github.io/py_win_unc/

Comment: been a while since I did this, but iirc the way I found is to call `net show` (sp?) and parse the output... don't have any windows machines nearby to try it now...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [win32wnet](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32wnet.html) from pywin32 to convert your drive letters.  For example:

```
import win32wnet
import sys

print(win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName(sys.argv[1], 1))
```

This gives me something like this when I run it:

```
C:\test>python get_unc.py i:\some\path
\\machine\test_share\some\path
```

Comment: Doesn't deal with local drives, instead use https://stackoverflow.com/a/45016081 by @njoosse

Comment: Local drives don't have a UNC name.  Only shared drives on a network will have them.  Anyway, I'd still recommend using pywin32 rather than rolling your own ctypes access to windows, including http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32wnet__WNetGetConnection_meth.html

Comment: Sorry, you're completely right. I was thinking about the error, which you can just catch of course.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to do it in python ≥ 3.4, with no dependencies!*

```py
from pathlib import Path

def unc_drive(file_path):
    return str(Path(file_path).resolve())
```

*Note: I just found a situation in which this method fails. One of my company's network shares has permissions setup such that this method raises a `PermissionError`. In this case, `win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName` is a suitable fallback.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ctypes` and the code shown in the first answer in this post: [Get full computer name from a network drive letter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801315/get-full-computer-name-from-a-network-drive-letter-in-python), it is possible to get the drive paths for every network drive, or a selected few.

The `get_connection` function given will throw an error if the drive is not a network drive, either local or removable drives, this can be accounted for with

```
# your drive list
available_drives = ['%s:' % d for d in string.ascii_uppercase if os.path.exists('%s:' % d)]
for drive in available_drives:
    try:
        # function from linked post
        print(get_connection(drive))
    except WindowsError: # thrown from local drives
        print('{} is a local drive'.format(drive))
```