# Why does my python (exe file) not work correctly when opened as a exe file?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, exe, pyinstaller

I have a python file that is simple and opens up webpages from a text file. It is supposed to work and **even works in visual studios.** I decided to turn it into a exe file using pyinstaller. It outputted a exe file just fine and I opened it but it did nothing and closed right after I opened it.

I used **Python 3** and downloaded the pyinstaller inside of **Anaconda**. Thank you

My code:

```
import webbrowser
print('Welcome to my project')
webfile = open('webfile.txt', 'r')
for lines in webfile:
    webbrowser.open(lines)

k = input('Press Enter to Exit')
```

Comment: How did you open the `exe` file, by double clicking or by terminal?

Comment: I opened it by clicking it. It open a prompt but did not do anything. Then it closed itself quickly after that.

Comment: The double click will execute the program in a new window and close the window when it terminates. How did you invoke pyinstaller to build the app?

Comment: I used this command inside the anaconda terminal: pip install pyinstaller. Next I used: pyinstaller C:\Hereismyprogram.py

Comment: Running your application as an .exe will happen in a different environment than as a script, maybe you can idle the window using `k=input("")` to see what the program is doing

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. It does not even print out 'Welcome to my project'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the times, when it comes to reading a file via the pyinstaller bundeled executable, you do not have the right path to the file.
Here are some ways you can get around it:

1. Enter the full path of the file. Note that this would not work when you want to use the executable on another machine. For example use `webfile = open('<full_path_to webfile.txt>', 'r')`
2. As your local paths are not the same when you have bundeled your application, it seems most likely that you will have to use an `if` condition to set the path of the expected file. There are many answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404744/determining-application-path-in-a-python-exe-generated-by-pyinstaller), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50302229/pyinstaller-not-finding-file-path-inside-program)) on SO which will explain this in further detail.

PS: It is not a good practice to read the file without a context manager. [This](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/) will explain why.