# PyInstaller exe finish at the huggingface pipeline line

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an exe using pyinstaller of huggingface model. My code is working without exe, but when i convert it into exe, it did not work. It did not throw any error. It just get finished.
Here is the piece of code

```
bundle_dir = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(bundle_dir,"nlpmodels", modelname))
print('dirs',os.listdir(path))
print('model path',path)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(path,local_files_only=True,truncation=True, model_max_length=512)
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(path,local_files_only=True)
classifier = pipeline('token-classification', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
print(' classifier',classifier)
```

here is output print statements

```
dirs['config.json', 'gitattributes.txt', 'pytorch_model.bin', 'README.md', 'special_tokens_map.json', 'tokenizer_config.json', 'vocab.txt']

model path C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\_MEI25162\nlpmodels\stanford-deidentifier-base
```

I also print out tokenizer  and model and I can see it in exe console. The content of dirs statement is same before and after creating exe.
Issue is that my code is not printing `classifier` statement.

Is there any way to get an idea whats going wrong. May be I can get some sort of error to see why its not working

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is

Comment: my code did not work as expected when i created the exe

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that pyinstaller can find the files.

a common issue is the use of relative paths. use this function to adjust the paths:

```
def get_correct_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50302455)

Comment: as the content of `os.listdir(path)` is same , it mean it found it

Comment: The point of this finction is to return the same, esp on the New file System of the pyinstalled Environment.