# How to get ip/hostname from python with admin rights

Tags: python, windows

How to get from a python script, running with cmd administrator rights, the hostname or ip from mapped letter?
with this post [Python 2: Get network share path from drive letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970700/python-2-get-network-share-path-from-drive-letter):

```
import win32wnet
import sys

print(win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName(sys.argv[1], 1))
```

This gives me something like this when I run it:

```
C:\test>python get_unc.py i:\some\path
\\machine\test_share\some\path
```

This works if I run without administrator privileges, but I need to run with admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `stdlib`:

```py
import socket

print('Hostname', socket.gethostname())
print('IP', socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
```

Comment: With this I just get the local machine, I need the mapped drive letter, for example, if i:\some\path is mapped to \\10.200.51.134, then it should return \\10.200.51.134\mypath\some\path