# Determine network path of shared drive on Windows in Python

Tags: python, windows

Consider a local drive on a Windows machine that is shared over a network.

The drive is mapped to `D:\` locally and it is shared by the local machine over the network with the name `data`. Therefore, the network path for this drive would be `\\computer-name\data`.

Is it possible to determine the name of the shared network path programatically in Python given the drive letter `D` from the host machine?

Expected behavior would be:

```
drive_letter = "D"
get_network_path(drive_letter)
>>> \\computer-name\data
```

The only additional constraint is that this should work without admin permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get full computer name from a network drive letter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801315/get-full-computer-name-from-a-network-drive-letter-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the full network path by using the `subprocess` module with `net share`, which will list all shared drives.

```
import platform
import subprocess


def get_network_path(drive_letter: str):
    s = subprocess.check_output(['net', 'share']).decode()  # get shared drives
    for row in s.split("\n")[4:]:  # check each row after formatting
        split = row.split()
        if len(split) == 2:  # only check non-default shared drives
            if split[1] == '{}:\\'.format(drive_letter):
                return r"\\{}\{}".format(platform.node(), split[0])

print(get_network_path("D"))   
>>> \\computer-name\data
```